# Initrd logs to a file on disk

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, initrd

I want to dump the initrd output to a file, what kind of changes either in bootloader some parameter which i can pass like console=tty or new process in initrd which can keep dumping logs to disk.

Answer (score 0):

This is a chicken-egg problem, before initramfs starts to mount the rootfs, how do you get the path of the file you want to dump the log?

After initramfs mounts rootfs and starts the /sbin/init on your rootfs, your log will be dumped to something like /var/log/messages, via syslogd or something like that.